# Strongly typing the arguments of a function using an enum, both in the same object

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics

Is there any way to type an object such that one property is a tuple of keys from a dictionary object, and the other property is a function whose arguments types derive from looking up those keys on the dictionary?

```js
type Dict = {
    s: string;
    n: number;
    b: boolean;
    d: Date;
}

const typedObjects: TypedObject[] = [
    { args: ['s'] , func: (s) => console.log(typeof s) }, // expect string
    { args: ['n'] , func: (n) => console.log(typeof n) }, // expect number
    {
        args: ['s', 'b'] ,
        func: (s, b) => console.log(typeof s, typeof b) // expect string, boolean
    }
]

// what should TypedObject be?
```

Taking the last element in my `typedObjects` example, I'd like TypeScript to infer that the `s` and `b` arguments are of type `string` and `boolean` respectively coming from that object's `args` array/tuple. If you were to include fewer or more arguments than what's in the tuple, TypeScript would give an error.

I'm open to other forms of syntax that accomplishes the same thing. I'm also really trying to avoid repeating anything.

My use case here is that my `Dict` is actually the shape of a web form after some initial transformation on form data, and I'm trying to strongly type multi-field validation functions with type safety on the inputs coming from the fields that will be used for that function.

Thank you!

Comment: Sorry are you using this at runtime? As typescript is not a runtime language and compiles out to javascript.

Comment: There's no scalable/usable specific type corresponding to `TypedObject`.  You could use a generic type instead along with a helper function to infer the type argument for you, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/NV7xMm).  Does that meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Thank you, that's exactly what I need. If I could I would promote your comment to the answer (or feel free to repost it and I will mark it as such). I do wish there were some way to do this in TypeScript at the object level instead of needing to wrap it in a function. A "type hint" of sorts for an object, but I'm sure there's reasons why at a fundamental level. I'm not sure what the right intuition would be for that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to dynamically check for array of `args` and generate function type from it, that's impossible
But you can make this interface to simplify your work

```
interface TypedObject<Obj extends Object> {
    args: (keyof Obj)[],
    func: (...args: Obj[(keyof Obj)][]) => Obj[(keyof Obj)]
}
```